# User.authenticate method returning nil in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

The User.authenticate method is returning nil even though the user exists in the database with the correct email and password.  This happens when calling the authenticate method from the Create action in the Sessions controller or from the Rails Console (irb).

Any help with this problem will be greatly appreciated.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def create
      user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                                   params[:session][:password])
      if user.nil?
        flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
        render 'new'
      else
        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
      end       
    end

    def destroy
      sign_out
      render 'pages/options'
    end

end
```

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,    
                  :account_type, :email_confirmed, :weight

  validates :password,  :presence => true,
                    :confirmation => true,
                    :length => { :within => 6..40 }

  before_save :encrypt_password

  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password) 
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
    user = find_by_id(id)
    (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil 
  end

  private #################################################

  def encrypt_password
    self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
    self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
  end

  def encrypt(string)
    secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
  end

  def make_salt
    secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
  end

  def secure_hash(string)
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
  end

  def generate_email_conf_code
    email_conf_code = secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}")
    self.email_conf_code = email_conf_code
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you tried narrowing it down and determining whether `find_by_email(email)` or `user.has_password?(submitted_password)` is causing it to return nil?

Comment: What does `params` look like when you get a `nil`? And which email and password are you expecting to match?

Comment: It is user.has_password?(submitted_password) that is returning nil. I still can't figure out why.  The proper params are getting submitted to user.authenticate.  I've checked that by dumping the params to a debug page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your server log. You can also monitor them directly on the terminal. Look for the  session email received on the server. It looks something like this on Rails 3.1.1

```
Parameters: {"session"=>{"email"=>"xxx@yyy.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

See that you're getting the email correctly. If not, I guess you know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

does your database store a password_digest or encrypted_password column?  Older tutorials by michael hartl used password_digest, now they seem they are encrypted_password.